# Inserting a '0' bit into the middle of a bitsequence in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, bit

This should be fairly simple, but I've yet to see a viable solution.

If I have a bit sequence (represented as an integer), how would I insert a 0 at index n?

For example:

```
insert(0b100101010101,4) -> 0b1001001010101

insert(0b101,3) -> 0b1010

insert(0b10001,2) -> 0b100001
```

EDIT: To clarify, I would like to do this without using vectors or strings (only bitwise operators)

Comment: convert to a string with `bin(...)`, insert the digits, then convert back to an int with `int(bitstring,2)`

Comment: Do you want to use bit operators only ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that in the post

Comment: Are your examples supposed to have `0b` pretended to them?

Comment: `insert(101,3)` is not going to get a number whose binary representation is 101, but whose decimal representation is 101. Is it really that what you want? Or did you intend `insert(0b101, 3)`?

Comment: It looks like you're indexing your bits from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Scratch that last comment, you're indexing from the left instead of the right. Very confusing.

Comment: @trincot The method invocation was meant to be more of a 'pseudo-code' representation to better display the desired output of the method. The number is given as a normal `int`

Comment: I have updated your question, because even in pseudo code, a number is decimal when no other indication is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to isolate the bits to the left and to the right of the insertion point, then shift the left part one position, and combine both parts again:

```
def insert(n, bit):
    length = n.bit_length()
    if bit > length:
        raise ValueError("argument out of range")
    right = n & ((1 << length - bit) - 1)
    return ((n - right) << 1) + right
```